# Gradually decrease the particular time and call server side event when time goes up

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want a show a time running in order to decrease by per second and when time lapsed a button event is called.

Comment: Ok - so go ahead and do it. Or is there something you'd like to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, say you want to start countdown from 1 minute and 10 second

```
var Hr = 0;
var Min = 1;
var Sec = 10;

var dt = new Date(2014, 01, 01, Hr, Min, Sec);

setInterval(function(){

    $("div").html(dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds());
    dt.setSeconds(dt.getSeconds() - 1);

    if(dt.getHours() == 0 && dt.getMinutes() == 0 dt.getSeconds() == 0)
        $("button").trigger("click");

}, 1000);
```